# Background of UINavigationController view turns white

Tags: iphone, memory, graphics, camera

My iPhone application uses the camera to take pictures, which I suspect is somewhat memory-intensive. The app uses a custom background image for the `view` of its `UINavigationController`, and after taking a few pictures, the background goes all white. Any ideas on what I can do to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the project was very specific about having a background image, so I had to retain it despite the memory waste.

My work-around was to unload the background once you've entered the photos-view, and then reload it before you leave. Not the most beautiful solution, but it works really well.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if -didReceiveMemoryWarning is being called in any of your viewControllers. If it's a low memory problem, that's probably the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Ben Gottlieb's post, is it really necessary for you to have the custom background image? That by itself is a big memory waste; I shutter (eh, camera pun) to think of combining the two without releasing the picture before redisplaying the tableView.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But it's not my choice: the client really wants it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, and resolved it by subclassing UINavigationController.

Then in the viewDidLoad method I simply create my background (ImageView) and add it to the view.

If your UINavigationController is created from a nib, just give it your custom class name in IB. I had to do that as I also have a custom navigationbar, which you can only set in IB.

Comment: **Override `UINavigationController`** how?

Comment: Override was probably the wrong word.

'@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end'